# AngularJS - ng-repeat inside of ng-grids cellTemplate

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-grid

Given the following data set:

```
{
    "url": "www",
    "words": [
        {
            "name": "fish",
            "count": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "pig",
            "count": 60
        }
    ]
},
{
    "url": "www",
    "words": [
        {
            "name": "zebra",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "cat",
            "count": 12
        }
    ]
},
{
    "url": "www",
    "words": [
        {
            "name": "dog",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "antilope",
            "count": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to create a grid that will look something like:

```
   URL     Words:Count
--------|--------------
|       |   fish:1    |
| www   |   pig:60    |
```

etc...

In my controller, I've tried is the follwing configuration:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'data',
        columnDefs: [
        {field:'url', displayName:'URL'}, 
        {displayName:'Words:Count', cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><div ng-repeat="word in row.entity.words">{{word.name + ":" + word.count}}</div>'}
  ]
}
```

But all i get is the first word:count, and not the entire set.

I've tried looking through the docs, but couldn't find anything,

what am i missing?

Comment: if you made a plunker i can help you, i have a lot of ng-grid fully personalized in my application:) i think you're problem is in the data format, but i have to see the plunker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the height of the grid? Here's [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UtGeuCnbsrreNf3nPRsT?p=preview) with your code and its working.

style.css

```
.gridStyle {
    border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
    width: 400px; 
    height: 300px;
}
```

javascript:

```
...

$scope.gridOptions = {
...

rowHeight: 80 // height of each row

...
};

...
```

index.html

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

Comment: Not the grid style, but rather the rowHeight property on the grids option object. Add that to your answer and i'll choose your comment as the answer.

Comment: forgot to add the styling part on my example, but it was there to begin with so it's less relevant. 
Thanks a bunch!